# How can I deploy an app on Heroku that is not located in the root directory?

Tags: django, heroku

I've got a project that has a directory structure as such:

```
├── backend
│   ├── backend-files.py
│   └── procfile
├── docker-compose.yml
└── frontend
```

I want to be able to deploy the Python backend (Django) on Heroku. As you can see it is located in it's own directory. However, Heroku does not allow me to specify a subdirectory when pointing to a github repo. This means that I would need my backend code to be at the root level in order to use their CD pipeline features.

Does anyone know of a way to modify my configuration in Heroku so that I can keep the directory structure as is?